# Show a stretch of numbers are composite/ not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq2$. Consider the numbers $n!+2,n!+3,...,n!+ n$. Show that none of them is prime. Deduce that for each positive integer $N$ there is a stretch of $N$ consecutive composite numbers.

The only idea I have is to show they are composite numbers you have to find a non-prime factor. Would anyone be kind enough to start me off?

**What I don't understand is what happens when n=2 and you work out n! + 3=5 which *is* prime.**

Comment: $n!+2$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: $n!+3$ is divisible by 3.

Comment: $n!+4$ is divisible by $4$.